# Solved :Array formula to find a series of number from uncertain row

Tags: google-sheets

Anyone Could help me with Arrayformula to find max value for this type of ada.
In a row there are series of number, always start with 0 (Zero) and followed by few numbers, then start again with 0 (Zero) and so on

What is the formula to find max value for uncertain row of numbers
Data 1 is 3 row,
data 2 is 2 row,
data 3 is 3 row
data 4 is 6 row and so on
its total random

Example Link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1av63sEiL5_0ZLbJaChutemPNJIAbxVTtqFwWS0IYoD0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet set up exactly as in your post, and being sure to set the link's Share permission (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "EDITOR." Otherwise, the volunteer contributors here would need to open a sheet of their own, set up all of your merged cells and manually enter data before they could even begin to help you. The most efficient way to help those here to help you is to provide access to such a spreadsheet. This way, those here will be able to jump right in, test, and leave you with any working solutions they devise for you.

Comment: Thankyou for input, i added to my post

Comment: Is the Column-A data with merged cells going to be part of the actual spreadsheet? If so, that is unclear from your shared spreadsheet, where data in Column B continues down past where Column A has data. Please clarify this and adjust the sample spreadsheet accordingly (i.e., either add merged Column-A cells for as far down Column B as there is data; or delete data in Column B that extends past where Column A has merged cells and data; or delete Column A altogether if it will not exist in the real-world spreadsheet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a sheet ("Erik Help"). Per my last comment to your original post (comment #3 overall), your data setup is not clear. So I have added two formula versions along with a note.

**Formula V1 (in C2):**

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"*",SORT(FILTER(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B),FILTER({ROW(B2:B),A2:A},A2:A<>""),2,TRUE)&"~"&TEXT(B2:B,"000"),B2:B<>""),1,0),1,FALSE),"~(.+)$"))))`

**Formula V2 (in D2):**

`=ArrayFormula(IF((B2:B="")+(B2:B>0),,VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(VLOOKUP(TEXT(ROW(B2:B),"000000")&"*",SORT(FILTER(TEXT(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B),FILTER(ROW(B2:B),ISNUMBER(B2:B),B2:B=0),1,TRUE),"000000")&"~"&TEXT(B2:B,"000"),B2:B<>""),1,0),1,FALSE),"~(.+)$"))))`

**My on-sheet note:**

Use the V1 formula in C2 if your real-world sheet will have merged data cells, since it is a bit simpler to digest. (Currently, it will only produce results    through Row 27, because that is as far as you have entered data in Col A.)

Use the V2 formula in D2 if your real-world sheet will not have data in Col A, and if results must rely solely on Col-B data. (This formula will work whether you have Col-A data or not; it's just longer than necessary, if you will have Col-A data.)

---

**ADDEDNDUM:** I recommend the solution posted by Tom Sharpe. It's the most straightforward approach. I had forgotten that pure numbers would sort in correct order without the conversions I used above. (Numbers in other situations sort 1,11,100,2,27, etc.) Being that they *will* sort in order without additional "fiddling," Tom's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*As an alternative to using formulae, you can do this with an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).*

#### Code Example:

```js
function getHighestValues(range) {
  const values = range.flat(2).join("-").split("-0-")
  const result = []

  values[values.length - 1] = values[values.length - 1].replace(/-+$/, "")
  
  values.forEach(function(dataRange, i) {
    dataRange = dataRange.split("-").map(x => parseInt(x))    
    if (i > 0) dataRange.push(0)
    result.push(Math.max(...dataRange))
    for (let j = 0; j < dataRange.length - 1; j++) {
      result.push("")
    }
  })
  return result
}
```

You can add this script by following the `Tools > Script editor` menu item, and copy+pasting this script into the editor. Make sure to save the script.

**Rundown of this function:**

- Gets all values of the column specified and splits them into groups separated by the value of '0'
- Loops through each group of values, and finds the largest number in the group.
- Pushes the largest number to the return array, and pads the array out with blank rows eaqual to the size of the group
- Returns an array of values.

**Usage:**
You can place the following formula into cell `C2`:

```
=getHighestValues(B2:B)
```

**Visual Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll put this one out there as well:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"",sort(B2:B,vlookup(row(A2:A),if(A2:A<>"",row(A2:A)),1,true),1,B2:B,0),))
```

[image]

What I'm trying to do is sort first on the group number (first row number of each group) obtained from the vlookup then on the value in B2.

Comment: Of course! I'd forgotten, in a moment of "midnight madness," that pure numbers will sort correctly without the conversions that they require in text format (i.e., that 1,2,10,20 will sort as-is and not as 1,10,2,20). Kudos.